# Creating one-item tuples from strings python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a couple of objects: some strings and some tuples. For every item that isn't a string, I would like to make it into a one-object tuple. Example:

```
s = 'spam' #turns into:
t = ('spam')
```

Then, I would like to append each one of those tuples to a list. Code:

```
mylist = []
items = ('spam', 'eggs', ('shrubbery', 1, 'toast'), ('foo', 'bar'))
#If not already a tuple, each item is converted into a tuple, then appended to `mylist`
#In the end, `list` should be:
mylist = [('spam'), ('eggs'), ('shrubbery', 1, 'toast'), ('foo', 'bar')]
```

I have already tried:

```
for i in items:
    if type(i) != tuple:
        i = tuple(i)
    mylist.append(i)
```

This turns every stand-alone string into a tuple of its characters, which isn't what I want.

How can I do this?

Comment: Don't use the name `list`; you are masking the built-in type now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one-item tuple is defined by the *comma*, not the parentheses:

```
>>> 1,
(1,)
>>> (1)
1
```

Parentheses are just used to delineate a tuple when commas could mean something else.

See [*Parenthesized Forms*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms) in the expressions documentation:

> A parenthesized expression list yields whatever that expression list yields: if the list contains at least one comma, it yields a tuple; otherwise, it yields the single expression that makes up the expression list.

So use:

```
if not isinstance(i, tuple):
    i = i,
```

note the use of `isinstance()` as well to test for the type.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a list comprehension:

```
>>> items = ('spam', 'eggs', ('shrubbery', 1, 'toast'), ('foo', 'bar'))
>>>
>>> [item if isinstance(item, tuple) else (item,) for item in items]
[('spam',), ('eggs',), ('shrubbery', 1, 'toast'), ('foo', 'bar')]
```